# How to set CSS style for certain table cells? (Eclipse RAP Platform)

Tags: eclipse-rap

If I create CSS class `Table-Cell`, it is used for all table cells.

```
Table-Cell {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

How can I set the padding to 5px for cells in first table column and 10px for cells in the second table column? How can I do that without RowTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not yet possible in RAP. You could try to enable [markup](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=markup.html&version=3.0) and include some whitespace character like U+2003 to add some padding.

The pseudo class `:nth-child` is not supported, only those that are defined in the [theming reference](http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/doc/3.0/guide/reference/theming/Table.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Table-Cell:nth-child(odd) {
    padding: 5px;
}

Table-Cell:nth-child(even) {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate using images what your final result should be?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
nth-child
```

pseudoclass:

```
table:nth-child(n) { ... }
```

Comment: @Paul i mean, table is the parent element, n is the table cell u want to set, or u can search for the "nth-child pseudoclass" by urself

Comment: @Paul I remembered that in css there's no column in fact but row, try to set every first child element of every row and second child element of every row, or simply use even/odd to replace "1" or "2"